# Сессии в PHP

Tags: сессия, php

Имеется два сайта **api.site.com** и **site.com**
Реализованы системы регистрации и авторизации.
Сама форма входа содержится на сайте **site.com**, а система на **api.site.com**
При успешной авторизации создается сессия на сайте **api.site.com**, но при обнавлении страницы она исчезает. Почему так происходит?
Сама суть в том, что если создать сессию на **api.site.com**, то она "держится" и если создать сессию на **site.com**, то она тоже "держится", а если сессия создается через сайт **site.com** на сайте **api.site.com**, то она при обновлении страницы исчезает. Сам код сайта **api.site.com** выполняется при помощи функции *file_get_contents* на сайте **site.com**

Answer (score 2):

В .htaccess прописываете:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".site.com"
```

или в php:

```
$lifetime = 100500; // время "жизни" или 0 - до закрытия браузера
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, "/", ".site.com", false, true);
session_start();
```

Comment: Ну так вот не работает. Все равно сессия умирает...